# Using named cell in case statment to end autofilter not working

Tags: excel, vba, reference

I want to use a cell defineds name rather the the actual cell reference (Case "$L$75") for the code to identify end of data for the Auto filter.  Currently just replacing the cell reference with the cell defined name errors.
The filter is not made available for the user to use which is why it is not just set up as a table.

```
Sub X_HideBlankRows_Angebot()

 ' ***** Hide Blank rows in Kosten Table

 ' x - Defined Cell Names ANKosten
 ' x                      ANKostenEndCell

Sheets("5_Angebot").Select

Dim c As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("ANKosten")        ' x
i = rng.Cells(1, 1).Column - 1

For Each c In Range("ANKosten")    ' x
    Select Case c.Address
    Case "$L$75"
       c.AutoFilter Field:=c.Column - i, Criteria1:="inUse", _
         Visibledropdown:=False
    Case Else
       c.AutoFilter Field:=c.Column - i, _
         Visibledropdown:=False
 End Select
Next

Range("B51").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are to compare the address and make a named range as reference, then you have to use the address of that range.

```
Case Range("NameOfRange").Address
```

Comment: Thank you that works fine.  Appreciate the explanation also to help for next time.